# How to Add Headers using Mail faced of Laravel 10

Tags: php, email, header, laravel-10

I' am using the below code set the smtp configuration first and then I'm trying to send the mail where I need to set some headers as well. But I am unable todo. Please see my codes and help me to reach my goals. Here is my code.

```
$stmp = [
            'mail.mailers' => ['user_stmp' => [
                'transport' => 'smtp',
                'host' => $sender_info->smtp_host_name,
                'port' => $sender_info->smtp_port,
                'encryption' => $sender_info->smtp_port == '465' ? 'ssl' : 'tls',
                'username' => $sender_info->smtp_user_name,
                'password' => $sender_info->smtp_password,
                'from' =>
                    [
                        //FIXME TWO BOTTOM LINES MUST BE GIVEN A DO OVER PROBABLY
                        'address' => $sender_email,
                        'name' => $sender_name,
                    ],
            ]]
        ];
        config()->set($stmp);
        Mail::mailer('user_stmp')->send('emails.reply', [
            'from' => $sender_email,
            'body' => $request->body,
        ], function ($m) use ($sender_email, $sender_name, $request,$reply) {
            $m->from($sender_email, $sender_name);
            $m->to($request->to_mail)->subject($request->subject);
            if ($request->cc)
            {
                $m->cc($request->cc);
            }
            if ($request->bcc)
            {
                $m->bcc($request->bcc);
            }

            /*$m->getHeaders()
                ->addTextHeader('Message-ID', $reply->message_id)
                ->addTextHeader('In-Reply-To', $reply->in_reply_to)
                ->addTextHeader('References', $reply->refs);*/
            $m->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) use ($reply) {
                $headers = $message->getHeaders();
                $headers->addTextHeader('Message-ID', $reply->message_id);
                $headers->addTextHeader('In-Reply-To', $reply->in_reply_to);
                $headers->addTextHeader('References', $reply->refs);
            });
        });
```

right now I'm getting the below error

```
"Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Mail\\Message::withSwiftMessage()"
```

Comment: `withSwiftMessage` is a method of the `Mailable` base class, but you are trying to call it on a `Message` instance here.

Comment: so how can i get my outcome, need to add headers

Answer (score 1):

withSwiftMessage() has been renamed to withSymfonyMessage() in Laravel 9.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/upgrade#symfony-mailer